# Remove "+ New Discussion" From Discussion Board

Tags: permissions, discussion-board

I've developed a sharepoint community site which is allowing some external users. I need these users to be able to read, comment, reply, to discussions, but not have ability to add new discussions. Can't seem to remove the "+ New Discussion" from the discussion board.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Edit the page containing the Discussion Board List. Select the web part and Click on Edit webpart. Select Toolbar Type to "No Toolbar" and save the webpart.

Answer (score 0):

Edit AllItems.aspx view page with SharePoint Designer and insert the below Jquery/Javascript, which hides it completely

```
if($('#forum0-NewPostLink').find('span')[1])
   $($('#forum0-NewPostLink').find('span')[1]).hide();
```